# No Query on Django Forms with Foreign Key

Tags: django, forms, foreign-keys

I am building a django form

My model is that a customer has a wish list.  A customer can have many wish list items.  I add a wish list item from a customer view.  My problem is that when I render my wish list form it has a drop down with ALL of the customers.  tI eliminated the drop down by setting `editable=False`.  But now I want to display the non-editable item on the form.  And pass the non-editable value back on Submit.

If I set editable to false on `Wishlist.customer` can I:

1. set this value in the view and pass it to html for display purposes
   only?
2. have the non-editable wishlist.customer passed back on form submit for processing?

---------models.py------------

```
class WishList(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, editable=False)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=True)
    item = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    sold = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

-------- forms.py ------------

```
class WishListForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = WishList
        fields = ['carType', 'year', 'make', 'model', 'miles', 'color', ]
```

--------views.py-------------

```
@login_required
def newWishList(request, customer_id):
    cust = Customer.objects.get(pk=customer_id)
    return handlePopAdd(request, WishListForm, cust, 'wishList')

def handlePopAdd(request, addForm, customer, field):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = addForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid(): 
            newObject = form.save()
    else: 
        form = addForm()
        # Here I want to set the customer and have it displayed, not editable
        form.customer=customer
    pageContext = {'form': form, 'field': field}
    return render_to_response("popuptemplate.html", pageContext)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you seem to have a typo in your form definition: it reads `felds` instead of `fields`. It also lists some field names that I don't see anywhere else in your code, so that probably won't do much just based on this snippet.

What I'd do is to just list the fields you want to have editable in your `ModelForm` (as you currently already do). Then either include the customer field, but override its display properties as outlined [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets): make it e.g. a `CharField` with the `readonly` attribute set.

Another option (my personal preference) is to just leave the customer out of the form entirely and render the customer name in the template, without making it part of the form at all. Put it in something like a header tag above your form to make clear what customer your data is about.